# Bind function trouble

Tags: c++, function, boost, reference, bind

I'm using boost (signals + bind) and c++ for passing function reference. Here is the code:

```
#define CONNECT(FunctionPointer) \
        connect(bind(FunctionPointer, this, _1));
```

I use this like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  void test1() {}
  void test2(int someArg) {}

  SomeClass() {
     CONNECT(&SomeClass::test1);
     CONNECT(&SomeClass::test2);
  }
};
```

Second test function binding works (test2), because it has at least one argument. With first test I have an error:

```
‘void (SomeClass::*)()’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

Why I don't able to pass functions without arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_1` is a placeholder argument that means "substitute with the first input argument". The method `test1` does not have arguments.

Create two different macros:

```
#define CONNECT1(FunctionPointer) connect(bind(FunctionPointer, this, _1));
#define CONNECT0(FunctionPointer) connect(bind(FunctionPointer, this));
```

But remember [macros are evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html).

And use it like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  void test1() {}
  void test2(int someArg) {}

  SomeClass() {
     CONNECT1(&SomeClass::test1);
     CONNECT0(&SomeClass::test2);
  }
};
```

Comment: Okay, I udnerstand. I know that macros are evil, but the body of my macros is big and ugly. Of course, if it would be like my sample, I'd use it.Thanks.